# How to add path aliases to next.js?

Tags: next.js

Based on [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) I know I can use a `jsconfig.json` file to manage paths.

But I have encountered two problems:

1. It's a JSON file and not a JS file. This means that I can't code in it. In Vite+React or CRACO we can write Node.js code to create path aliases.
2. It seems that the `paths` property does not work for `jsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@": [
                "components"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So, my first question is that how can I add path aliases to next.js via code?

And my second question is that why `import Button from '@/Button'` does not work while I have specified the `@` to point to `compnents` directory and the `baseUrl` to point to the root of the project?

**Update**

Let's say I have this structure:

```
- components
    - Index
        - Exports.js
        - Hero.js
        - Pricing.js
        - Stats.js
        - Testimonials.js
    - Shared
        - Button.js
        - Exports.js
        - Section.js
        - Title.js
- pages
```

And inside each `Exports.js` I have exported all sibling modules:

```
import Hero from './Hero'
import Pricing from './Pricing'
import Stats from './Stats'
import Testimonials from './Testimonials'

export { Hero }
export { Pricing }
export { Stats }
export { Testimonials }
```

Then why this path alias does not work?

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "Index": [
                "components/Index/Exports"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And inside `index.js`:

```
import { Hero, Pricing, Stats, Testimonials } from 'Index'
```

Comment: T‍‍‍‍‍ry this```"paths": { "@/*": ["components/*"] }```

Comment: @FaridVatani, that's too dirty. We use path aliases to clean things up. Using a symbol and a slash results in dirty import statements. Could you please look at the **update** to my question?

Comment: What do you mean by "dirty import statements"? @FaridVatani's suggestion will let you use `import Button from '@/Button'` as you wanted originally, assuming your component is located at `/components/Button`.

Comment: Given your update, that path aliases configuration works with that folder structure for me (see https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-elbakyan-eixdcm?file=/pages/index.js). Did you restart your development server after making the changes?

Comment: @juliomalves, yes the problem was that I had to restart my server. By dirty I mean dirty. `from 'Index'` is much cleaner than `from '@/Index'`. It's easier to maintain. It's easier to read. It's easier to memorize and to write. It's easier to be told to a team.